# What error type do you use for a function called at the wrong time?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, state-machine

I have a Python 3 class representing a finite state machine, with functions for actions to transition from state to state.

What type of error should I raise if a user calls `actor.take_train()` while `actor.state` is `BED`, or if a user calls `actor.sleep()` while `actor.state` is `WORK`? That last case is probably also ill-advised at most workplaces, but you do you.

The function call is valid sometimes, but invalid at others, and I'm unaware of whether there is a defined error appropriate to raise in this case.

[image: Finite state machine]
*Image courtesy of [Dwarves Foundation](https://dwarves.foundation/playbook/finite-state-machine/)*

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're specifically looking for an exception, probably a custom one derived from RuntimeError (ValueError would be the closest of the standard exceptions but it's not quite a match).

But *whether* to even throw an exception is a consideration of the specific use case for the state machine, and what's more useful / convenient e.g. you might want to just log the invalid signal and do nothing, or return a placeholder of some sort.